# How can I turn off curent app running in the lastest Genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion

http://postimg.org/image/6wp5fo0sl/

I want turn off current app running, but I can't swipe it down,swipe it up,long click..... in short, I can't do anything. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you push the wrong button. long push the home button (triangle with square below it)

Comment: Thank man, make this as answer and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push the wrong button. Long push the home button (triangle with square below it)